# Codeigniter ajax tooltip

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, tooltip

I want to make pop up tooltips with dynamic data from db when cursor hover to link, but I'm doing something wrong. Correct my code please.

My view

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tip').tooltip();
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       $('#something').mouseover(function(){
        $.ajax({
         url: "<?=base_url();?>aircraft/tip",
         type: 'POST',
         data: {
          'id': $(this).attr("rel"),
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(aircraft_j) {
                  $('#something').attr('data-original-title',aircraft_j);  
              }
        });
        return false;
       });
      });
      </script>

    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" id="something" title="" 
data-original-title="" rel="1" class="tip">aircraft</a>
```

My controller

```
 function tip() {
    $this->output->enable_profiler(false);
    if($this->input->server('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') != 'XMLHttpRequest'){ echo "fail. try something else"; return; }
    $this->load->model('aircraft_model');
    $idd = $this->input->post('id');
    $aircraft_j = array();
    $aircraft_j = $this->aircraft_model->get_aircraft_tip($idd);
    echo json_encode($aircraft_j);
    }
```

My model

```
 function get_aircraft_tip($idd) {
    $this->db->where('id',$idd);
    $query = $this->db->get('aircraft');
    return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Are you getting an error?  What are you expecting the output to be?  You need to ask a good question to get good answers.  "correct my code" does not help us.

Comment: @Miguel-F Are you getting an error? - no, i getting nothing and that is the problem. when cursor hover the link, i want to div with id tooltip will recorded result that returns the controller.

Comment: what tool tip are you using?

Comment: @mamdouh-alramadan i use bootstrap but, this is my first experience with jquery/ajax and I don't know how and where to stick bootstrap tooltips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as you said that you are using **[bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips)** tooltip. here's how you should do it:

in your html:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" id="something" title="" 
data-original-title="tooltip data goes here">whatever you want</a>
```

and as I can see you have no problems with your `ajax` and CI `controller` but you have to make a slight change to your `success function` like this:

```
success: function(aircraft_j) {
                  $('#something').attr('data-original-title',aircraft_j);  
              }
```

**Also:** you can read about [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) which might be helpful to you.

### Problems you might face..

In your `CI tip function` I see `echo json_encode($aircraft_j);` so your `$aircarft_j` variable should be a '**string**' data type. As I can see you are returning `$query->row_array();` from your model, **so you might need to work with it as an array** . [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564991/ajax-form-validation-with-mysqli-query/14565715#14565715)  you can find a good explanation about that.

Comment: I did everything you said, but after testing, I discovered a problem. Data in success function is empty. You said that $aircraft_j must be string type. For testing i made this: $aircraft_j = '1'; After this data was empty. I think that problem may be with json_encode but don`t know why.

And one more question. Can i combine result with html in the controller and then give it to view? Or better combine in view?

Comment: I gave you an example of compiling. I didn't say that it should be string. The link I provided helps you with arrays if you like. There are multiple posts about that. Can u tell me what is the result of alert (aircraft_j) inside the success.  And if it is empty please paste your modified code so I can see better through your problem

Comment: About combination you can do both. But doing the process inside ur controller and passing it to the view os better because you're following the mvc work here

Comment: result of alert (aircraft_j) is empty. i inserted modified code in first post.

Comment: okay.so you are passing an array. so please paste the result of `console.log(aircarft_j)` which you can see in firebug. and check that the model is returning data actually.

Comment: fuf. i found problem. "tip" function in the aircraft controller was conflicted with other function. when i moved it to separate controller, everything is ok. and one more little question. json_encode return screening ("\/")html. that is, instead bold text i see <b>text<\/b>. i googled but didn`t find normal solve. may be you know?

Comment: for passing html change the type of ajax to `html` instead of `json` and in you controller use `echo $something` instead of `echo json_encode($someting)`